# JDK association issue

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm running redhat-release-client-6Client-6.5.0.2.el6.x86_64 and have installed Oracle SQL Developer as well as my Java JDK, and both "work" but when I try to run `sqldeveloper` I am asked to associate the JDK path. I've spent close to 2 hours now reading and researching about this issue and I'm still unable to figure it out.

```
[root@nameless bin]# readlink -f $(which java)
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65.x86_64/jre/bin/java
[root@nameless bin]# sqldeveloper

 Oracle SQL Developer
 Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Type the full pathname of a JDK installation (or Ctrl-C to quit), the path will be stored in /root/.sqldeveloper/4.0.0/product.conf
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65.x86_64/jre/bin/java
Error: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65.x86_64/jre/bin/java/bin/java not found
Type the full pathname of a JDK installation (or Ctrl-C to quit), the path will be stored in /root/.sqldeveloper/4.0.0/product.conf
^C[root@nameless bin]# 
[root@nameless bin]# locate java | grep '/java$'
/etc/java
/etc/alternatives/java
/etc/pki/java
/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java
/usr/java
/usr/bin/java
/usr/java/jre1.7.0_55/bin/java
/usr/lib/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/Scripts/java
/usr/lib64/libreoffice/ure/share/java
/usr/share/java
/usr/share/doc/db4-devel-4.7.25/java
/usr/share/doc/db4-devel-4.7.25/ref/java
/var/lib/alternatives/java
[root@nameless bin]#
```

Comment: What does *associate the JDK path* mean? Have you tried setting `JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: put the path in when it says `Type the full pathname of a JDK installation (or Ctrl-C to quit), the path will be stored in /root/.sqldeveloper/4.0.0/product.conf`

Answer (score 2):

Try taking out the /bin/java from the path you are including - just give the JRE's base directory (`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65.x86_64/jre`). It looks for bin/java inside the path you provide - you do not need to add that manually.

You can see from the error that the program is appending an extra /bin/java to the end of where it should.

Comment: Since it says `Type the full pathname of a JDK installation`, you should probably give the path of the JDK, not the JRE.

Comment: In my experience, SQL Developer is looking for the JRE within the JDK, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

You've specified the path to the JRE, you need the JDK -

```
 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/
```

If you want to use Java 7 you'll need to get a JDK. Your exact error

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65.x86_64/jre/bin/java/bin/java
```

is the base directory but sqldeveloper is adding bin/java to your entry (so you can't).

Comment: When I try to give it a path it adds forward slashes to what I enter:

`Type the full pathname of a JDK installation (or Ctrl-C to quit), the path will be stored in /root/.sqldeveloper/4.0.0/product.conf
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/`

`Error: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64//bin/java not found`

Comment: @Joshua Try adding the jre then, double slashes is fine there. If "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre" works then the instructions are just very poorly worded. For Java 7, try "/usr/java/jre1.7.0_55" or "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65.x86_64/jre" depending on which you want.

Comment: It told me to add 'SetSkipJ2SDKCheck true' to my   /root/.sqldeveloper/4.0.0/product.conf and SQLDeveloper opened when I did that, so we'll see. Thanks.